# Detect application close vs change in Activity or DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I seem to have hit a limitation with the lifecycle of my application.

I have an activity which uses a Google API. At some point I make a connection to that API and it attempts to connect. On the first attempt it fails to connect because we haven't selected an account and authorised it. As a result the Google SDK launches `connectionResult.startResolutionForResult` - a method which basically just shows an account selection DialogFragment.

When the SDK method is invoked it triggers `onPause` on my Activity.

This is a problem because my `onPause` method calls `disconnect()` on the Google API (as is good practice). The problem then being that I *do* want to disconnect when closing the activity/application but I *don't* want to start disconnecting while I'm resolving the account problem (in the background I am reattempting the connection which will be successful as soon as the user picks their Google account, there doesn't seem to be a callback to detect when it happens)

What's the piece of this puzzle that I am missing?

Comment: Can't you move `disconnect()` to `onStop()`?

Comment: Thought about that first then doubted myself. I'm pretty sure there is no guarantee onStop will be called. do you know for sure? - this article http://iswwwup.com/t/1d599768dd67/is-activity-onstop-guaranteed-to-be-called-api-11.html is a great explanation of why I'm unsure

Comment: According to the `Activity` lifecycle `onStop()` will be called except the low memory situations (which is anyway not idea situation). See this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29 I believe you should be fine.

Comment: Ironically low memory is exactly when I *want* to make sure to cleanup things like an active API client. For now I've already implemented onStop anyway until anyone comes up with anything better

Comment: Ok. Try setting a boolean variable to true when the dialog is opened. When this bool is true don't disconnect. Don't forget to set it to false otherwise you won't disconnect ever.

Comment: Thought of that too, seemed like a hack. I was just really hoping there was some built in mechanism to check why we are being paused

Comment: As per the documentation this is the desired behavior. Sorry but I can't think of anything better right now.

Comment: @rohit5k2 as much as I want another answer yours seem to be correct/confirmed. Why don't you put it all in an answer I can accept, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideal scenario would be to move `disconnect()` to `onStop()`

According to the Activity lifecycle [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStop%28%29) `onStop()` will be called except the low memory situations (which is anyway not idea situation). I believe you should be fine.

But in any case if you want this `disconnect()` method to be called in low memory scenario then probably you should keep this method in `onPause()` and take a boolean flag. Set it to true when the dialog is opened. When this boolean flag is true don't disconnect. Don't forget to set it to false otherwise you won't disconnect ever

These are the two solutions I could think of. Hope it helps.